# Why is react-native-biometrics not working in my project? Cannot read property isSensorAvailable of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fingerprint

I am trying to create a user-authentication application using fingerprint scanner. But the react-native-biometrics library is not working.
It is in the node-modules, it seems i am on autolinking react-native. This is really slowing me down.

Help please.

This is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeBiometrics, { BiometryTypes } from 'react-native-biometrics'
//import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';

//const fingerPrintImage = require('../../assets/images/fingerPrint.png');

const LocalAuthg=(props)=>{
    const rnBiometrics = new ReactNativeBiometrics({ allowDeviceCredentials: true });


    rnBiometrics.isSensorAvailable()
      .then((resultObject) => {
        const { available, biometryType } = resultObject

        if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.TouchID) {
          console.log('TouchID is supported')
        } else if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.FaceID) {
          console.log('FaceID is supported')
        } else if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.Biometrics) {
          console.log('Biometrics is supported')
        } else {
          console.log('Biometrics not supported')
        }
    })
    return(
        <View style={ styles.fingerPrint }>
            <Text style={ styles.fpText } allowFontScaling={ false }>One-Touch Login</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default LocalAuthg;
```

I get the error : "Typeerror: cannot read property isSensorAvailable of null"

I tried linking with react-native link library

I also tried to do a manual setup but nothhing

Comment: while i checked with the latest react native project with the libraries latest version did not face any kind of issue .  i checked with the code provided by you , it worked .

Comment: Is this an expo project?

Comment: @nazmul how can the code work with you when it doesn't with me? How did you create your app.

Comment: @ThanhalPA i think it is a react-native app. It is a blank react native application created with create-react-native-app

Comment: I created with npx react-native init..

Answer (score 1):

As per my finding [expo doeasn't support react-native-biometrics](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/issues/251#issuecomment-1604350667).

So either you can use [expo-local-authentication](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-local-authentication) in your current project which is created using **`Expo`** or you can use **[React Native cli](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&os=windows&platform=android)** to create a new project which allows linking.

> Expo restricts access to certain native modules, which means you may
> encounter limitations when trying to integrate certain third-party
> libraries or accessing low-level device features. Where as React
> Native CLI allows you to access and integrate any native module
> available in the React Native ecosystem, giving you the flexibility to
> leverage a wide range of third-party libraries and device capabilities

You can read more about this here : [Expo vs React Native CLI](https://medium.com/@softworthsolutionspvtltd/expo-vs-react-native-cli-7e47c7630039)

Answer (score 0):

Check for you package.json and package-lock.json if react-native-biometrics is installed.
I had the same issue, as the entry in package.json was missing.
resolved it by reinstalling the package. Also check for the manual linking steps
include use_biometrics permission in androidmanifest.xml
hope this helps!